# Finding the value(s) of $a$...

Tags: linear-algebra

> For which value(s) of $a$ is the column $\boldsymbol{\mathrm x} = \begin{pmatrix}2a \\ a^2 \\ -8\end{pmatrix}$ a linear combination of the columns $\boldsymbol{\mathrm y} = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\boldsymbol{\mathrm z} = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2 \\ -1\end{pmatrix}$?

Do we find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $$\alpha\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}+\beta\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
2 \\
-1
\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}
2a \\
a^2 \\
-8
\end{bmatrix}??$$ Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well, try to solve for $\alpha$ and $\beta$.  You should see that you can do it for some $a$ but not for others.

Comment: Re write this as a system of three equations with three unknowns ($\alpha$, $\beta$, and $a$). First use the third equation to get $\beta$ then get the other two.

Comment: That is what it means for one vector to be a linear combination of the others, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

This is equivalent to:
$$
\begin {cases}
\alpha+\beta=2a\\
\alpha+2\beta=a^2\\
-\beta=-8
\end{cases}
$$
and you must find for what values of $a$ this system has solutions.